# cakephp 2.2.4 edit action data not updating into database

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

here is my edit action

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
    }
```

I tried to update one row but got below error
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bsmltravel@2016.users.id' in 'where clause'

```
SQL Query: UPDATE `bsmltravel@2016`.`users` SET `id` = 1, `username` = 'test', `password` = 'test', `status` = 1, `created_by` = 1, `modified_by` = 1, `modified` = '2016-08-02 14:21:59' WHERE `bsmltravel@2016.users.id` = '1'
```

Comment: Query need to be UPDATE `users` SET `username` = 'test', `password` = 'test', `status` = 1, `created_by` = 1, `modified_by` = 1, `modified` = '2016-08-02 14:21:59' WHERE `id` =1

Comment: `print_r($this->request->data);` what it outputs? show us

Comment: @Anant i think data is okay but problem in where clause 
that is "WHERE `bsmltravel@2016.users.id` = '1'"

Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => test
            [password] => test
            [status] => 1
            [created_by] => 1
            [modified_by] => 1
        )

)

Comment: seems you somehow changed the `primaryKey` attribute value in your User Model...

Comment: @arilia if I changed the primary key in Model so that how can i insert the data into database .after successful bake i do nothing . just add  a row and try to update that row sql query comes up : SQL Query: UPDATE `bsmltravel@2016`.`users` SET `id` = 1, `username` = 'test', `password` = 'test', `status` = 1, `created_by` = 1, `modified_by` = 1, `modified` = '2016-08-02 14:21:59' WHERE `bsmltravel@2016.users.id` = '1'

Comment: check your Model/User.php file and see if primaryKey  is changed. Also: bsmltravel@2016.users.id means somethig to you?

Comment: yeah, i mean that in where clause it looks odd to me. whatever this is my model file code :                                                           App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 */
class User extends AppModel {

}

Comment: try put $primaryKey  = 'id' in User.php

Comment: @arilia tried but no luck. same error like as above